# How to set button's label without changing value in post

Tags: html, forms

I've got this code in html:

```
<form action="/login/" method="post">
<input type="text" name="login">
<input type="text" name="pass">
<input type="submit" value="login"  name="type" >
<input type="submit" value="register" name="type" >

</form>
```

When I submit this form it sends a `get` request with the value of the field of the button clicked. However I want to change the label of the button without changing the value sent in `get`. Is it possible or not?

Comment: first, you have two `action` attributes. The second should be `method="POST"`

Comment: `its` in the title does not need an apostrophe

Answer (score 3):

Use a button element:

```
<button type="submit" name="type" value="register">Sign up for an account</button>
```

Note that [old IE has problems with this](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/forms/multiple-submit-buttons.html).